# How can I generate a lint-results.xml file when building my project in Android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I would like to generate a lint-results.xml file when building my project in Android studio. I need to be able to do this in order to use the following: https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover

I have also tried building the project from the command line but I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'lint' not found in root project 'client-android'. Some candidates are: 'init'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Here are my gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'bugsnag'

android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

lintOptions {
    // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
    quiet true
    // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
    abortOnError false
    // if true, only report errors
    ignoreWarnings true
}

compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mango.android"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        setRoot('src/test')
    }
}
}

 robolectric {
   include '**/*Test.class'
 }

dependencies {
     repositories {
         mavenCentral()
     }

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile files('libs/android-sqlite-asset-helper.jar')
compile('com.google.inject:guice:4.0-beta:no_aop') { exclude module: 'asm' }
compile('org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0') { exclude module: 'asm' }
compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0' // For parallax views
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
androidTestCompile files('libs/android-sqlite-asset-helper.jar')
androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
    exclude module: 'classworlds'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
    exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
    exclude module: 'maven-model'
    exclude module: 'maven-project'
    exclude module: 'maven-settings'
    exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
    exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
    exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
    exclude module: 'wagon-file'
    exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
    exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
}
androidTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}

idea {
     module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes')
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:+'
}
}


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.14.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can export Lint XML in Android Studio 1.3:

1. At top, click "Analyze"
2. Select "Inspect Code"
3. Click OK.
4. An Inspection panel should open at the bottom (if not, you should be able to click on "Inspection" at the bottom left to open this).
5. Select "Android Lint" from the list so that it is highlighted.
6. Click the icon with the green up arrow (second from bottom left) to Export.
7. Select XML format, and choose the folder you want to save the results to.

I'm not sure if Android Studio has always included Lint, or if Android Studio began including Lint at some later date.  You may wish to go to Help -> About to check which version you are running.  If you are running an older version, go to Help -> "Check for Updates" to update Android Studio.

Comment: but is there a way to generate it from terminal? I would likes to have a xml report with unused res.

Comment: Haven't done it but yes this you can generate Lint XML from Terminal.  I think you just use the command "Lint" + the directory you want to check.  See instructions and examples here: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this (on Windows 10) in your project folder cmd line:

```
./gradlew lintRelease
```

Comment: for me, this generates a lint-results-release.xml